# Animate cubic player with one mesh

Tags: animation, mesh

I've just begining modelising and animation 3D for a game I need to realise for an internship

I have my player designed like minecraft player (cubic). So I need to make a walking animation and the software (superpowers) require only one mesh and one material for animation.

So I can't figure out how should I animate my player with only one mesh.

Thanks for help

PS: you can find the player model here http://www.kenney.nl/assets/3d-characters I just took it because I'm awful at modeling

I have to convert all mesh in one for the purpose of the software otherwise it can't read animation so I'm asking how I can animate different parts with only one mesh

lemon thanks for answering but the problem is that I made animation with keyframe and after joining mesh it animate the whole body with the same animation

Comment: The characters are correctly rigged... what is your question exactly?

Comment: Ok... I've seen the pending edit: simply join the mesh parts (select them and ctrl+j).